# How to reuse fxcop.xml in SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, fxcop

We have FxCop analysis being run by Nant/Jenkins. A SonarQube C# analysis is then triggered, and executed successfully.

We'd like to reuse `fxcop.xml` result file from Jenkins for Sonar's analysis.

We tried this configuration with no luck:

```
sonar.fxcop.mode=reuseReport
sonar.fxcop.reportsPaths=fxcop.xml
```

SonarQube is asking for path to `FxCopCmd.exe`. If specified, Sonar is running FxCop analysis one more time. We don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Are-sonar-fxcop-mode-reuseReport-and-sonar-cs-fxcop-mode-skip-supported-td5032472.html) `sonar.fxcop.mode` is no longer supported.

Quoted from the thread:

> You can skip the execution of FxCop on a specific project by using
>   another Quality Profile for it, that does not contain any FxCop rule.
>
> Indeed, it is important for the evolution of a project's technical
>   debt to be trackable over time. Changes in the rules that are applied
>   during the analysis has an obvious impact on the technical debt, and
>   therefore should be tracked.
>
> The "sonar.fxcop.mode" property did not allow that, and was therefore
>   removed. For example, with the reuseReports mode, you could launch
>   just 1 or 2 rules, whereas in SonarQube all FxCop rules are enabled.
>   Skipping the FxCop analysis fully when all FxCop rules are enabled in
>   SonarQube is obviously deceiving.
>
> The reuseReports mode should not be required, as SonarQube is able to
>   drive FxCop's execution.

I guess FxCop should be started from Sonarqube direct.